# What does the multiplication symbol :* do?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, enumerable

In particular, using inject, the following scripts,

- `puts (1..5).inject {|x, y| x * y}` and
- `puts (1..5).inject(:*)`,

both have output `120` as I expected.

However, the script

```
print [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map {|x, y| x * y}
```

has output

```
[2, 12, 30]
```

as expected but the script

```
print [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map(:*)
```

raises an `ArgumentError`:

```
confused_ruby_map_inject.rb:1:in `map': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from confused_ruby_map_inject.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Why is this happening, what does `:*` do, and what's the most concise way to achieve the result I'm looking for with the second set of scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inject()` can take a block or a symbol, but `map()` always takes a block.  I think your working `map()` is concise enough.

`:*` is the symbol name for the multiplication method.

**Update:** I think your working `map()` is fine, but it seems like what you might be looking for is the classic map/reduce, even though it's actually longer:

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map{|a| a.reduce(:*)}
```

Comment: Thanks (+1)! Is there a way, other than explicitly writing out the block, to convert an existing method like `*` to a block or proc? Something like `map(to_proc(*))`?

Comment: Well, you can convert the symbol to a proc with `:*.to_proc`, but no elegant use of that comes to mind for this case.  The closet thing I think there is to what you want is the classic map/reduce: `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map{|a| a.reduce(:*)}`.

Comment: after coming back to this and looking around for different options, it appears that indeed map/reduce is basically the closest possible solution to what i want. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the following way:

`[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].collect{|t| t.inject(:*)}`

Here you can see how the inject works [Enumerable Doc's](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

`inject` has special syntax; you can get close with map using an ampersand:

```
print [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map(&:first) #=>[1, 3, 5] #note the ampersand

print [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]].map(&:*)     #=>in `*': wrong number of arguments(0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

The error is because the [*-method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2A) takes an argument (either a string or a integer), which is not optional. It is the error you'l get when executing `[1,2].*`.

Demo of what `*` does:

```
p [1,2]*2       #=> [1, 2, 1, 2]
p [1,2]*' and ' #=> "1 and 2"
```